# Symmetric Inequality in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: calculus, inequality

Let $a, b$ and $c$ be posetive real numbers such that $abc=1$. I want to prove this inquality
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{ab}{a^5+b^5+ab}\le 1$$
I used AGM inequality but I didn't prove it.

Which should I use inequality? So thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [rearrangement Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rearrangement_inequality). Note
$$\frac{ab}{a^5+b^5+ab}\le \frac{ab}{a^4b+ab^4+ab}\\
\frac{bc}{b^5+c^5+bc}\le \frac{bc}{b^4c+bc^4+bc}\\
\frac{ac}{a^5+c^5+ac}\le \frac{ac}{a^4c+ac^4+ac}\\
$$
therefore
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{ab}{a^5+b^5+ab}\le \sum_{cyc}\frac{ab}{a^4b+ab^4+ab}=\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{a^3+b^3+1}=\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{a^3+b^3+\color{red}{abc}}\tag 1$$
Similarly
$$\frac{1}{a^3+b^3+abc}\le \frac{1}{a^2b+ab^2+abc}\\
\frac{1}{b^3+c^3+abc}\le \frac{1}{b^2c+bc^2+abc}\\
\frac{1}{a^3+c^3+abc}\le \frac{1}{a^2c+ac^2+abc}\\
$$
thus
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{a^3+b^3+abc}\le\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{a^2b+ab^2+abc}\le \sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{ab}\left(\frac{1}{a+b+c}\right)\le\underbrace{\frac{1}{a+b+c}\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{ab}}_{\frac{1}{a+b+c}\times\frac{a+b+c}{abc}=\frac{1}{abc}}=1\tag 2 $$
$(1)$ and $(2)$
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{ab}{a^5+b^5+ab}\le1$$

Comment: What is rearrangment inequality?

Comment: Please check it:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rearrangement_inequality

Answer (score 3):

This is an IMO 1996 Shortlist problem. Here is a [solution.](https://mks.mff.cuni.cz/kalva/short/soln/sh961.html) Another one [here.](http://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c2340h1032325)

Well if you consider the approach in the first link I shared, you can do everything with some bunch of AGMs. Consider the following

\begin{align*}
2a^4 + 2b^4&= a^4 + b^4 +a^4 + b^4\\ 
&\geq a^4 + b^4 + 2a^2b^2 \\
&= (a^4 + a^2b^2) + (b^4 + a^2b^2) \\
&\geq 2a^3b + 2ab^3 \\
\end{align*}

Here we showed $a^4 + b^4 - a^3b -ab^3 \geq 0$. Therefore
\begin{align*}
a^5 + b^5 &= (a+b)(a^4 + b^4 - a^3b -ab^3 + a^2b^2)\\
&\geq (a+b)a^2b^2
\end{align*}
Which means
\begin{align*}
\frac{ab}{a^5 + ab +b^5} &\leq \frac{ab}{(a+b)a^2b^2 + ab}\\
&\leq \frac{1}{(a+b)ab + 1}\\
&= \frac{c}{a+b+c}\\
\end{align*}
Note: You can do without "Rearrrengement".

Comment: Why $a=b=c$ ???

Comment: It just says when $a=b=c$ the inequality you have becomes equality. They are not equal in general.

Comment: Thanks Which should we use inequality?